# Where to find xen/common/schedule.c

Tags: nautilus, xen

I have installed xen and its working and I have made domu also. But I need to make changes in scheduler of xen and thats why I need to find xen/common/schedule.c. In my friend's computer if he is writing on dashboard he is able to find on desktop. I dont know where it is in my computer.  I have made the files unhidden also or maybe it is in any folder I dont know. I also need to find root/xen-4.0-testing.hg but same problem persists.  Please help to find these files

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu don't have this file in any of his packages.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xen-4.0-testing.hg&mode=exactfilename&suite=raring&arch=any

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=schedule.c&mode=exactfilename&suite=raring&arch=any

Please, ask your friend where he got it but I can assure you that Ubuntu doesn't have it. He may have the source code of some xen package, since the `.c` extension means that it's the C file in the sources.

Answer (score -1):

1 - install apt-file

2 - enable source code repos

3 - then as root run apt-file update

4 - after that you can search throug the contents of non-installed packages

example:

$ apt-file search 'xen/common/schedule.c'